# Password guess game

Tags: c++

Thanks for helping me guys I been trying to do password guess matching, but Im having some issues. The problem is for example my random password generate is 1624, and then when input ask me type guess password I type 1325.
Therefore, output is: OXOX . 
O means Correct, and X means incorrect

However,  how can specify was thinking using if statments. At the moment, I store every positions  from generate password, and the guess password into in array.

This was my idea :

```
if ( x[0] == y[0] && x[1] == y[1] && x[2] == y[2] && x[3] == y[3] ){
                cout << " OOOO" << endl; 
  }
```

******* CORRECTION:****

The problem that have if use  x[i] == y[i] what if I go to i = 1? how is gonna still comparing position 0,1,2,3 ? I need to match individually every character! and right now if i =0  i would only compare 0 and the rest would be ignore it! this what i mean:

generate password: 1234

int i = 0; x = 0;
guess input: 1845
output:  OXXX

int i = 1; x = 1;
guess input: 1200
output: OOXX

int i = 2; x = 2;
guess input: 0230
output X00X

This how my code looks right now

```
void randomClass () {
        std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(s), 10,
                        []() { static char c = '0'; return c++; });
        // s is now "0123456789"

        std::mt19937 g(std::random_device{}());

        // if 0 can't be the first digit
        std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(1, 9);
        std::swap(s[0], s[dist(g)]);

        // shuffle the remaining range
        std::shuffle(s.begin() + 1, s.end(), g); // non-deprecated version

        // convert only first four
        x = std::stoul(s.substr(0, 4));
        std::cout<<x << std::endl;

        //Store array
        y[0] = x/1000;
        y[1] = x/100%10;
        y[2] = x /10%10;
        y[3] =  x %10;




        }

    void guess (string b) {
        int x[4];

        for ( int i =0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << "Make a guess:" << endl;
        getline(cin,b);
        int u = atoi(b.c_str());
        x[0] = u/1000;
        x[1] = u/100%10;
        x[2] = u /10%10;
        x[3] = u %10;




        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all combinations of your...

```
if ( x[0] == y[0] && x[1] == y[1] && x[2] == y[2] && x[3] == y[3] ){
    cout << " OOOO" << endl; 
}
```

...just handle one character at a time...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    cout << (x[i] == y[i] ? 'O' : 'X');
cout << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the number as a string of characters. The number can then be accessed using array indices.

It's easier to compare `guess[2]` than it is to divide then use modulo to extract the digit.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    //  get input from user
    std::string input;
    std::cin>>input;

    //  set password
    std::string password = "1234";

    //  find size of lowest element string
    int size = fmin(input.size(),password.size());

    //  loop through all elements
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        //  if current element of input is equal to current element of password, print 'x', else print '0'
        std::cout<<(input[i]==password[i]?"X":"0");
    }
}
```